# Angular 2 ngModel and index with select element

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular2-ngmodel

I have a ng for loop like so

```
<template ngFor let-game [ngForOf]="(games)" let-index="index">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrice" class="form-control" name="">
                <option *ngFor="let price of prices">{{price}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Obviously, changing the price for one  element changes it for all the other  elements.

Here's a fork of what I mean when you change one drop down it changes the other.
https://plnkr.co/edit/LVViSdlgmY56RnO8mAU4?p=preview

My question is: is there a way to utilize the index in the template element to only bind one selectedPrice for each  element generated? So when I change the value of one dropdown value it doesn't change them for all the others

I've tried certain syntaxes like [(ngModel)]="selectedPrice[index]" which doesn't do what I want meaning when I select a price, the selectedPrice[index] doesn't actually contain a value. I have a few other ways that works but they're hacky.

Comment: Clarify this *doesn't do what I want*.

Comment: I clarified what I meant and updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/nOQ4ve9ee2A1TZjvrQBS?p=preview

```js
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i='index'">
        <td>
          {{game.name}} {{i}} {{game.price}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <select [(ngModel)]="games[i].price" class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let price of prices">{{price}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {}
  
  prices = ['40$', '30$', '20$'];
  games = [{name:'ge64'}, {name:'SM64'}];
  
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code. The `selectedPrice` variable now contains selected value.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrice" class="form-control" name="" (change)="select()">
            <option *ngFor="let price of prices">{{price}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <input id="result">
  `,
})

export class App {
  constructor() {}

  prices = ['40$', '30$', '20$']

  select(){
     document.getElementById('result').value = this.selectedPrice;
     console.log(this.selectedPrice);
  }
}
```

**[Plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/aK188lwkTWltrK0lYBby?p=preview)**

Comment: I've tried this and although it works, is there a simpler way utilizing index without creating another input value?

Comment: @Garuuk This method is even simplier: https://plnkr.co/edit/vVYutQrTCu2wvZOnR4L6?p=preview

Comment: I forked your plnkr to show you what I'm talking about. https://plnkr.co/edit/LVViSdlgmY56RnO8mAU4?p=preview  - notice when you change one drop down the other changes. I'm trying to get it so only one changes

Comment: @Garuuk You want to change the name of game together with price change?